# Add Tkinter to AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tkinter, dependencies, aws-lambda

I want to use Tkinter with AWS Lambda,I copied the **tkinter** folder from the lib folder: C:\Users\AGOJSO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter

And then made a zip file containing the tkinter folder and lambda_function.py, I made a ZIP file and uploaded it to AWS Lambda.

Then on top of the code i wrote:

`from /tkinter import *
tk = Tk()`

getting this error:

`Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 4)`

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to run tkinter on AWS lambda. Tkinter requires a display.

Comment: Ok, I have a script that stops instances, but I wanted to use Tkinter to warn the user about the instance shutting down, If not Tkinter what should I use?

Comment: With AWS SNS you can email or send an SMS to a user to action if need be